# Create array of objects with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an array of object:

```js
let data = [{
    createdDate: "2222"
    email: "test5@test.com"
    histories: []
    meta: {
      profilePic: "test"
    }
    name: {
      first: "Vikash",
      last: "Grv"
    }
    role: {
      id: "123",
      name: "test role 2"
    }
    specialities: []
    status: "active"
    __v: 0
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    createdDate: "2222"
    email: "test5@test.com"
    histories: []
    meta: {
      profilePic: "test"
    }
    name: {
      first: "Vikash",
      last: "Grv"
    }
    role: {
      id: "123",
      name: "test role 2"
    }
    specialities: []
    status: "active"
    __v: 0
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    createdDate: "2222"
    email: "test5@test.com"
    histories: []
    meta: {
      profilePic: "test"
    }
    name: {
      first: "Vikash",
      last: "Grv"
    }
    role: {
      id: "123",
      name: "test role 2"
    }
    specialities: []
    status: "active"
    __v: 0
    _id: "123"
  },
]
```

I want to create another array of an object like:

```js
const data = [{
    teamMember: 'Vikas Grv',
    email: 'test5@test.com',
    role: 'test role 2',
    assignedOn: null
  }, {
    teamMember: 'Vikas Grv',
    email: 'test5@test.com',
    role: 'test role 2',
    assignedOn: null
  },
  {
    teamMember: 'Vikas Grv',
    email: 'test5@test.com',
    role: 'test role 2',
    assignedOn: null
  }
]
```

the data in team member is the contamination of name (first and last key value), email is direct, role is from role --> name key value and assigned is null

and idea on how to do this

Comment: Please at least make an attempt at solving the issue yourself before posting. While there may be people who will answer your question, you'll learn much more if you make an attempt yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `map`:

```js
var data = [{createdDate: "2222",email: "test5@test.com",histories: [],meta: {profilePic: "test"},name: {first: "Vikash", last: "Grv"},role: {id: "123", name: "test role 2"},specialities: [],status: "active",__v: 0,_id: "123"}, {createdDate: "2222",email: "test5@test.com",histories: [],meta: {profilePic: "test"},name: {first: "Vikash", last: "Grv"},role: {id: "123", name: "test role 2"},specialities: [],status: "active",__v: 0,_id: "123"},{createdDate: "2222",email: "test5@test.com",histories: [],meta: {profilePic: "test"},name: {first: "Vikash", last: "Grv"},role: {id: "123", name: "test role 2"},specialities: [],status: "active",__v: 0,_id: "123"},];

var result = data.map(({name, role, email})=>({teamMember:Object.values(name).join(" "), email,role:role?.name, assignOn:null}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if role is not present in some object

Comment: @juhi In this case we can put an `condition operator` here. like this `role?.name`. Have a look at answer. I have update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    {
      createdDate: "2222",
      email: "test5@test.com",
      histories: [],
      meta: { profilePic: "test" },
      name: { first: "Vikash", last: "Grv" },
      role: { id: "123", name: "test role 2" },
      specialities: [],
      status: "active",
      __v: 0,
      _id: "123"
    },
    {
      createdDate: "3333",
      email: "test3@test.com",
      histories: [],
      meta: { profilePic: "test" },
      name: { first: "jhon", last: "doe" },
      role: { id: "123", name: "test role 3" },
      specialities: [],
      status: "active",
      __v: 0,
      _id: "1234"
    },
    {
      createdDate: "4444",
      email: "test5@test.com",
      histories: [],
      meta: { profilePic: "test" },
      name: { first: "nathy", last: "gyr" },
      role: { id: "123", name: "test role 4" },
      specialities: [],
      status: "active",
      __v: 0,
      _id: "1234"
    },
  ]

  constructor() {

    let result = this.data.map((item) => {
      return {
        teamMember: item?.name?.first + item?.name?.last,
        email: item?.email,
        role: item?.role?.name,
        assignedOn: null
      }
    }

    );
    console.log(result)
  }

}
```